# Parsing λ-terms using a very simple grammar

Tags: beginner, parsing, rust, grammar

This is my first Rust program. It parses a string into a λ-term using a very simple grammar.
Please evaluate style and use of ownerships / borrowing.

```
// λ-Terms are either lambdas, variables or applications.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Term {
    Lam {bod: Box<Term>},
    Var {idx: u32},
    App {fun: Box<Term>, arg: Box<Term>}
}
use Term::{*};

// Source code is Ascii-encoded.
type Str = [u8];

// A context is a vector of (name, value) assignments.
type Context<'a> = Vec<(&'a Str, Option<Term>)>;

// Extends a context with a (name, value) assignments.
fn extend<'a,'b>(nam : &'a Str, val : Option<Term>, ctx : &'b mut Context<'a>) -> &'b mut Context<'a> {
    ctx.push((nam,val));
    ctx
}

// Removes an assignment from a context.
fn narrow<'a,'b>(ctx : &'b mut Context<'a>) -> &'b mut Context<'a> {
    ctx.pop();
    ctx
}

// Parses a name, returns the remaining code and the name.
fn parse_name(code : &Str) -> (&Str, &Str) {
    let mut i : usize = 0;
    while i < code.len() && !(code[i] == b' ' || code[i] == b'\n') {
        i += 1;
    }
    (&code[i..], &code[0..i])
}

// Parses a term, returns the remaining code and the term. Syntax:
// - lam:   #var body      -- same as: λvar. body
// - app:   /f x           -- same as: f(x)
// - def:   @var val bod   -- same as: bod[val/var]
// - let:   :var val bod   -- same as: (λvar. bod)(val) 
fn parse_term<'a>(code : &'a Str, ctx : &mut Context<'a>) -> (&'a Str, Term) {
    match code[0] {
        // Whitespace
        b' ' => parse_term(&code[1..], ctx),
        // Newline
        b'\n' => parse_term(&code[1..], ctx),
        // Lambda
        b'#' => {
            let (code, nam) = parse_name(&code[1..]);
            let (code, bod) = parse_term(code, extend(nam, None, ctx));
            let bod = Box::new(bod);
            narrow(ctx);
            (code, Lam{bod})
        },
        // Definition
        b'@' => {
            let (code, nam) = parse_name(&code[1..]);
            let (code, val) = parse_term(code, ctx);
            let (code, bod) = parse_term(code, extend(nam, Some(val), ctx));
            narrow(ctx);
            (code, bod)

        },
        // Let
        b':' => {
            let (code, nam) = parse_name(&code[1..]);
            let (code, val) = parse_term(code, ctx);
            let (code, bod) = parse_term(code, extend(nam, None, ctx));
            let bod = Box::new(bod);
            let fun = Box::new(Lam{bod});
            let arg = Box::new(val);
            narrow(ctx);
            (code, App{fun,arg})
        },
        // Applicationn
        b'/' => {
            let (code, fun) = parse_term(&code[1..], ctx);
            let (code, arg) = parse_term(code, ctx);
            let fun = Box::new(fun);
            let arg = Box::new(arg);
            (code, App{fun,arg})
        },
        // Variable
        _ => {
            let (code, nam) = parse_name(code);
            let mut idx : u32 = 0;
            let mut val : Option<Term> = None;
            for i in (0..ctx.len()).rev() {
                if ctx[i].0 == nam {
                    val = ctx[i].1.clone();
                    break;
                }
                idx = idx + (match &ctx[i].1 { &Some(ref _t) => 0, &None => 1});
            }
            (code, match val { Some(term) => term, None => Var{idx} })
        }
    }
}

// Converts a source-code to a λ-term.
fn from_string<'a>(code : &'a Str) -> Term {
    let mut ctx = Vec::new();
    let (_code, term) = parse_term(code, &mut ctx);
    term
}

fn main() {
    // Parses the following λ-program:
    //   two = λf. λx. f (f x)
    //   exp = λn. λm. m n
    //   exp two two
    println!("Parsed λ-term: {:?}", from_string(b"
        @two #f #x /f /f x
        @exp #n #m /m n
        //exp two two
    "));
}
```

Obviously the most innovative thing about Rust to me is the ownership system, so comments on whether I'm using resources correctly are specially appreciated.

Comment: You're generally passing around slices of the source string, rather than copying, which is good.  From a style perspective, you might want to turn the Context type into struct, onto which you can attach the other functions as methods. It should make some of the code cleaner as you can elide some of the lifetimes and reference the context via `self` instead of the argument.